# Uniform Convergence and Compact interval

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I showed that $f_n = \dfrac{nx^2 + 4n^2x -1}{x^2 + 4nx +4n^2}$, on a compact interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$.

The question in my mind is: what does the compact interval change? When we consider the whole real line, this is not convergent uniformly, but this is on a compact interval. What is the reason for that?

Comment: I do not think that the convergence is uniform. For any fixed $N$, $x^2$ is the dominating term both in the nominator and the denominator. That means that for any $N$, $x > x(N)$ implies $f_N(x) \approx N$.

Answer (score 1):

We want to look at
$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \lvert x-\frac{nx^2+4n^2x-1}{x^2+4nx+4n^2}\rvert
$$
bring everything to a common denominator
$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \lvert \frac{{x^3+4nx^2+4xn^2}}{{x^2+4nx+4n^2}}-\frac{nx^2+4n^2x-1}{x^2+4nx+4n^2}\rvert = \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \lvert \frac{x^3+2nx^2+1}{x^2+4nx+4n^2}\rvert
$$
Note that for any fixed value of $n$ that the numerator is ${O}(x^3)$ but the denominator is $O(x^2)$ which means this error can grow arbitrarily large. As such the $\sup$ does not exist over all real numbers for each $n$ so over $\mathbb{R}$ this does not uniformly converge.

Comment: I have $f_n(x) = \dfrac{nx^2 + 1}{2n +x}$ and I showed that $f_n$ converges to some f uniformly. Now I need to show that $f'_n$ converges to g such that $g = f'$ Because I want to utilize the following theorem: Let $f_n:[a,b]→ℝ$ be a sequence of differentiable functions whose derivatives $f′_n$ are continuous. If $f_n$ converges uniformly to f and $f′_n$ converges uniformly to g, then the limit f is differentiable, and its derivative is $f′=g$. Then does it mean $ f' \neq g$?

Comment: which function did you show your initial $f_n$ sequence uniformly converges to?

Comment: I found $1/2x^2$

Comment: that doesn't uniformly converge on $\mathbb{R}$ either, are you sure you are doing it on the whole domain and not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Does it turn out to be okay if I work on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I edited it and made the set compact.